# How do I implement a picture instead of my red rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame

I cant seem to add a picture from a file instead of the red rectangle that is being displayed. 
This is only one class of my code.
I have looked at other tutorials on how to do this but i haven't had any luck. When i tried adding the image.load command, I kept getting a black window without anything on it.
I would like the image to be displayed instead of the red rectangle, but still with the same x and y values etc.

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.x_change = 0
    self.y_change = 0
    self.jump_duration = 15
    self.jumping = False
    self.jump_cooldown = 0
    self.move_unit = 5
    self.jump_cooldown_duration = 0
    self.width = 200
    self.height = 200
    self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
    self.image.fill(RED)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y

def move(self, movement):
    if movement == "":
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0

    if movement == "L":
        self.x_change =- self.move_unit

    if movement == "R":
        self.x_change = self.move_unit

    if movement == "U" and self.jump_duration >= 0 and self.jump_cooldown == 0:
        self.y_change =- (self.move_unit + 1)
        self.jump_duration -= 1
        self.jumping = True
        print("jumping")

    if self.jump_duration<0:
        self.jump_duration=10
        self.jump_cooldown=10
        self.jumping=False

def start_jump_cooldown(self):
    if self.jumping:
        self.jump_cooldown_duration = 60

def update(self, movement):
    if movement == "L":
        self.x_change=-self.move_unit
    if movement == "R":
        self.x_change=self.move_unit
    if self.jump_duration<0:
        self.jump_duration=5
        self.jump_cooldown_duration=10
        self.jumping=False
    if self.jump_cooldown_duration>0:
        self.jump_cooldown_duration-=1

    self.x += self.x_change
    self.y += self.y_change

    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

Comment: did you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? show code where you load image.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pygame.image.load`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) function to load the image from your hard disk and assign it to the `self.image` attribute in the `__init__` method of your class.

If the file is in a subdirectory you should construct the path with the `os.path.join` function, so that it works correctly with different operating systems.

The [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or `convert_alpha` for images with transparency) method should be called to improve the performance.

```
import os
import pygame

pygame.init()
# The display has to be initialized.
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
# Pass the path of the image to pygame.image.load.
MY_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('image.png').convert_alpha()
# If the image is in a subdirectory, for example "assets".
MY_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', 'image.png')).convert_alpha()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = MY_IMAGE  # Assign the image.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
```

Comment: We use uppercase names like `MY_IMAGE` to signalize that it's a constant and shouldn't be changed.